# Best methods for staging tables you updated in Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, staging, amazon-redshift-spectrum

Just a brief question on early thoughts about best methods for staging tables in Redshift for update-insert-delete approaches (for a continual basis ) process in Redshift.

Thanks

Comment: really - a lot more info required for your use case! things to consider include how you are going to be updating the staging tables and how you are going to use them.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to use `COMPUPDATE OFF STATUPDATE OFF` while loading data to staging table in Redshift. This will make the data load faster. If you want to know why, you can read more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-load.html)